# how to align svg image at the middle of the line?

Tags: html, css

How to align spinner svg image at the middle of the line(vertical)?

You can see below that the small spinner image is not aligned exactly at the middle. It is more like top left corner of the line. I appreciate any guide as to how to make it align perfectly at the middle of the vertical line.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please post what code you have so far?

Comment: can you share your code or working demo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

selector {
   vertical-align:middle;
}

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

.svg_image{display:block;margin:auto;}